# How to populate /usr/src and /lib/modules on WSL2 running Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ uname -r
5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

I would like to be able to run [tracee](https://www.aquasec.com/products/tracee) from a docker container, but it does not work on WSL2:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ sudo docker run --name tracee --rm --privileged --pid=host -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro -v /usr/src:/usr/src:ro -v /tmp/tracee:/tmp/tracee aquasec/tracee:0.4.0 --trace comm=ls
2023/05/16 00:37:43 missing kernel source code compilation dependency
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

I understand that is because `/usr/src` (and `/lib/modules`?) is empty on my machine.

How can I populate them given it is not a real Linux box, but WSL2?

Comment: perhaps that docker wasn't made to run on WSL

Comment: I think it just needs the kernel sources and so the question how to set them up for WSL2

Comment: sources or headers? if it's headers then perhaps installing `linux-headers-{kernel version}-{architecture}` will be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Using the distro's `linux-headers` package doesn't work here because the distro's kernel is not what's used in WSL2.  Instead, Microsoft has a custom kernel that they ship, and all of the stuff in it is compiled in so it doesn't need an initramfs (which means it boots faster).  Thus, `/lib/modules` is empty intentionally.  Using the distro headers will result in a binary that simply doesn't load in your kernel since it will be for a different version.

It used to be that the WSL2 kernel did not support modules at all, but that has changed, [according to the repository](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/).  There is some documentation associated with that repository about how to build a kernel, but it doesn't appear that Microsoft ships any sort of pre-built headers for this that can be used.  You could, however, clone the repository under an appropriate subdirectory of `/usr/src` and build the kernel and/or any necessary modules there using the documentation.